# Unable to run any command on mac terminal

Tags: macos, unix, sudo

I have changed by mistake the mode of `/usr` to `644` on my mac from terminal so now non of my process is accessible.

I can't use sudo and I am unable to find any way to login as root user so I will be able to change `/usr`'s mode back to 777.

Please give me any suggestion

Here is the error it shows when I open new tab in terminal.

```
could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty
```

Comment: `777` isn't the right perms anyway.  I would suggest running *Fix File Permissions* from `DiskUtil`.  You may also have more success asking this on the [right site](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Great brother you have saved my day :). Let me post the complete answer so other people will get help from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed trojanfoe's suggestion.
Here are the steps to fix this issue:

```
On system boot press Command+R it will take you to OS X Recovery
Click on Repair Disk Utility
Select your disk where os is installed
Click on repair file permissions
```

It will repair your permissions now you just need to restart your mac.